# bad_alloc when calling new on class Texture

Tags: c++, new-operator, bad-alloc

This is the offending line:

`Texture *texture = new Texture (...);`

I receive from bad_alloc here:

```
void *__CRTDECL operator new(size_t size) _THROW1(_STD bad_alloc)
    {       // try to allocate size bytes
    void *p;
    while ((p = malloc(size)) == 0)
            if (_callnewh(size) == 0)
            {       // report no memory
            static const std::bad_alloc nomem;
            _RAISE(nomem);
            }

    return (p);
    }
```

size is ~28 bytes big

and so far the program has placed maybe 2 MB on the heap in a 32bit system (fresh reboot) and before this only about twenty things get allocated on the heap so I know there's no heap corruption.

I'm so confused...

Comment: Is that on Windows? What memory consumption does Task Manager show for this process?

Comment: If there is enough memory in the system, `_callnewh` must be failing. Are you calling `set_new_handler` somewhere above? Can you post the code for the constructors of `Texture `?

Answer (score 1):

Heap corruption doesn't necessarily mean "too much memory allocated"; rather, it often means that you have screwed up with some pointers.

Check whether you made some mistakes like that, since you are saying that you haven't exhausted the memory.

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN, _callnewh():

> This function throws bad_alloc if the
>   new handler can’t be located.

So you haven't correctly installed the 'new handler' using `_set_new_handler()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think for this issue you can refer to >>[Item 07](http://docs.online.bg/PROGRAMMING/effective_c++/EC/EI7_FR.HTM) of Effective C++.